# How do I refactor v-model with get,set and toggle function in this case?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

I have vue templates that is toggled each by a function for **v-show** and its corresponding getter and setter for **v-model**:

```
 <p>To : <span v-show="!emailToSW">{{toEmailSet}}</span>
      <input v-show="emailToSW" type="text" v-model.lazy="toEmailSet" />
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleEmailTo();">{{emailToSW ? ' ' : ' '}}</a>
 </p>
```

```
 toggleEmailTo(){
   this.emailToSW = !this.emailToSW;
 },
```

```
 toEmailSet:{
    get(){
      return this.componentGetObject.toEmail 
    },
    set(val,$event){
      return this.componentSignal({pro:'toEmail',ev:event.target.value}) 
    }
```

it's getting cumbersome when you have dozens of pair like this with only changing variable name.

is there a way to refactor toggle and v-model getter and setter for this case so it will accepting more general variable, not hard-coded `toEmail` or `emailToSW` in this case?

**Addition**:
Actually I'm using vuex for each object properties mutations like so:

```
Vue.set(state.componentObject, payload.pro, payload.ev)
```

Triggered on mounted for complete initial object:

```
mounted:function(){
    this.componentObject(this.items) //local state copied to mutations
  }
```

and the redundant functions is like this:

```
<p>Fault Occurring Time: </p>
    <span v-show="!startDateSW">{{startDateSet}}</span>
    <input v-show="startDateSW" type="text" v-model.lazy="startDateSet" />
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleStartDate();">{{startDateSW ? ' ' : ' '}}</a>
```

dozens of them :D
being member of items object:

```
items:{toEmail:'xxx',startDate:'yyy', ... ...}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for this component? I have a couple ideas, but need to see a bit more of the implementation.

Comment: I see this as being its own component. The toggle control would be an internal data item, it would `v-model` the `toEmail` variable and would receive the signal callback and variable name as props.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've implemented a snippet using both your code and a component to model the same things. The component should be called with `value` instead of `v-model` since the component calls `componentSignal` rather than emitting an `input` event.

You can see that they both work the same and affect the same things (I made `componentSignal` set the value of the variable, but it can do whatever you want it to).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    emailToSW: true,
    componentGetObject: {
      toEmail: 'hello'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleEmailTo() {
      this.emailToSW = !this.emailToSW;
    },
    componentSignal(obj) {
      console.log('Set', obj.pro, 'to', obj.val);
      this.componentGetObject[obj.pro] = obj.val;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    toEmailSet: {
      get() {
        return this.componentGetObject.toEmail
      },
      set(val) {
        // set does not return anything
        this.componentSignal({
          pro: 'toEmail',
          val
        })
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    lockableInput: {
      template: '#lockable-input',
      data() {
        return {locked: false};
      },
      props: ['value', 'signal', 'pro'],
      computed: {
        proxyValue: {
          get() { return this.value; },
          set(newValue) { this.signal({pro: this.pro, val: newValue}); }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        toggleLocked() { this.locked = !this.locked; }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>To : <span v-show="!emailToSW">{{toEmailSet}}</span>
    <input v-show="emailToSW" type="text" v-model.lazy="toEmailSet" />
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleEmailTo();">{{emailToSW ? ' ' : ' '}}</a>
  </p>
  <lockable-input :value="componentGetObject.toEmail"
  :signal="componentSignal" pro="toEmail"></lockable-input>
</div>

<template id="lockable-input">
  <p>To : <span v-show="locked">{{proxyValue}}</span>
    <input v-show="!locked" type="text" v-model.lazy="proxyValue" />
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleLocked();">{{locked ? ' ' : ' '}}</a>
  </p>
</template>
```

Comment: Ah I see. It took me some time to grasp the `<lockable-input>` things. of course it can be modeled with component. Duh.. Many Thanks..

Comment: One little problem though, `<lockable-input>` always rendered with newline in the main app, I can of course adding extra props for its prefix, but I wonder if I could make something like : `comment before <lockable-input .../>` really inline in the main?

Comment: Put a class on the `<p>` tag and add css to set its `display: inline-block`